# Question about showing stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, random-walk, stopping-times

I'm having a trouble about how to show $T$ is a stopping time. For instance, suppose $X$ is a simple random walk on $I = \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$, and $T$ is the first time $n$ such that $X_0, \dots, X_n$ cover entirely $I$ ($T = \infty$ if never happen).

By following the definition I got
We say that $T$ is a stopping time if for all $n \in N$, $\{T ≤ n\}$ only depends on $(X_0, \dots , X_n)$, i.e. there exists a set $A_n \subset I_{n+1}$ such that $\{T ≤ n\} = {(X_0,\dots, X_n) \in A_n}$.

My question is, if $n=k$, we have $X_0, \dots X_n$ cover entirely $I$, but $X_{n+1}=X_0$, does it make $T$ a stopping time?

Another question is, if $T$ is finite, does the probability of $X_{T+2}=X_T$ is $1/k$?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: If $n=k$ that doesn't mean $X_0,\dots,X_n$ cover $I$. For example if $n=k=3$ then $(0,1,0)$ could be a valid 3-steps walk. Also not sure what you mean with $X_{n+1}=X_0$.

Comment: @ScapeProf Thanks a lot for your attention and your answer. Here I’m thinking if $n$ covers $I$ entirely, then $n+1 = 0$, since in this case $I=Z/(n+1)Z$.(Probably my thinking is wrong)

Comment: Sounds like you don't understand what they mean with simple random walk on $I = \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$. It means we start at $0$ and  go one step back with probability $0.5$ and go one step forward with probability $0.5$ and then we look at it modulo $k$. So if $k=3$ then 1st step it can either go to $-1=2 \mod 3$ or to $1 \mod 3$.

Comment: @ScapeProf Ah, ok, I see, then I get what does it mean, thanks!

Comment: @Uther Do you now understand why the $\ T\ $ defined in your first paragraph satisfies the definition you've given for a stopping time?